# Renaming TV show episodes using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, television

I want to rename my TV shows as per the episode and the series they are from. My TV shows are generally in the format '[Show name].SabEyz.blabla.mp4', e.g, Futurama.S07E01.HDTVx264.mp4'
I want to rename them in this format 'Episode xy - [Show name] - Series ab.mp4'

I tried using the following:

```
    for %%a in (*S07E??*.mp4) do ren '%%a' 'Episode ?? - Futurama - Series 7.mp4'
```

But it gave me an error that the specified file was not found

As you can see the above script cannot be used generally for all the series of the same show. I would like to do something about that too. Thank you!

Comment: First, you should change to real quotes `"%%~a"` instead of `'%%a'`. The `??` can't be used the way you tried it. You need more batch logic here

Comment: try the [Advanced Renamer](http://www.advancedrenamer.com/), best renamer for video files! :T

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=." %%a in ('dir /B *.mp4') do (
   set sXXeYY=%%b
   ren "%%a.%%b.%%c" "Episode !sXXeYY:~4,2! - %%a - Series !sXXeYY:~1,2!.mp4"
)
```

Comment: Can you expand on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=." %%i IN ('dir /b/a-d *.*.*.mp4') DO (
 SET seriesep=%%j
 SET /a series=1!seriesep:~1,2! - 100
 SET /a episode=1!seriesep:~-2! - 100
 ECHO REN "%%i.%%j.%%k.mp4" "Episode !episode! - %%i - Series !series!.mp4"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This should do the rename as specified - well, it'll `ECHO` the rename command to the screen - remove the `ECHO` keyword to activate the rename.

Not sure whether you want to retain or suppress the leading `0`s. If you want to retain them, change (eg)

```
 SET /a series=1!seriesep:~1,2! - 100
```

to

```
 SET series=!seriesep:~1,2!
```

OR

substitute `!seriesep:~1,2!` for `!series!` in the `[echo] REN` line.